# reset - issue UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

My view controller:

```
class myViewController: UIViewController {
   var myvar = 0

   func count() {
     print(myvar)
     myvar+=1 
   }

}
```

---

Other view controller:

```
Interval(1) {
  myViewController().count()
}
```

---

The code above is the code I got so far. But there seems to be an big issue:

The var called `myvar` gets kind of new initialized and so always gets it default value "0".

Why does`myViewController` get reset after calling `myViewController().count()`? How can I get rid of this behavior?

**EDIT: The "myViewController" was never loaded before, maybe this causes the issue?!**

---

**EDIT:** There must be some other way then just generating instances. Because multiple files are using multiple instances and this will cause error again! (cause a reset)

Any help would be VERY appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering two of your questions:

1. Why:

`myViewController` is your Class. `myViewController()` is an instance of a class. You may have an unlimited quantity of instances of one class. And all of them by default will have a value `0`. If you expect to see something else but not a `0` then you should get that particular instance of a class where you increased the `myvar` variable.

2. How to get rid:

There is no way to get rid of this. This is how it works.

Solution: please share with us your business logic / goal / explain what are you trying to achieve / what are you building / what's the final result?

But my guess is you want to do this:

```
let myControllerInstance = myViewController()
myControllerInstance.count()
myControllerInstance.count()
print(myControllerInstance.myvar) // expect 2 here
```

UPDATE: if it doesn't get called then call it:) maybe set an "initial view controller".

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing a new instance of myViewController every time you call myViewController().count().

I guess instead you should have something like:

```
 let myVC = myViewController()

Interval(1) {
myVC.count()
}
```

Comment: You should use delegation or Notifications to update the myvar value from different VC's

Answer (score 0):

`myViewController` is the name of your view controller implementation. `myViewController()` is a call to initializer of that view controller implementation without any parameters. That means, `myViewController()` create a new instance. You call `myViewController().count()`, which increments the value, but for that newly created instance.

What you need here is to get a reference to a single `myViewController` instance that you present on the screen. Without knowing more about hierarchy of your view controllers, it is impossible to tell you how to get it (although you should have now an idea of what is a problem and how to approach it).

Answer (score 0):

> The var called `myvar` gets kind of new initialized

Not kind of, it does get new initialized.

There is a common mistake / misunderstanding: The default initializer `myViewController()` creates always a brand new instance of the controller which is different from all other instances and – more important – from the instance designed in the storyboard.

The way you can get rid of the issue depends on your design which is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

```
myViewController()
```

This line of code right here creates a new instance of myViewController.   myvar is set to zero upon creation of a myViewController.  This is why it appears myVar is "being reset to zero" each time your interval function is called.

```
var myvar = 0 //Called whenever you use myViewController()
```

A more explicit way to write your class to make it more obvious would be:

```
class myViewController: UIViewController {
    var myvar: Int
    init() {
        myvar = 0
    }
...
```

**Solution**

```
let vc: myViewController = myViewController()
Interval(1) {
    vc.count()
}
```

**Pro Tips**

Welcome to the world of programming!  I'm very excited for you!

Stick with standard naming conventions: rename myViewController to MyViewController.

Don't increment a variable in a function named count.  Logically, it makes no sense.  Somebody, even you, later on may use this function, and forget that count() increments that internal variable.  Instead, change count to do just that, get the count.

**Pro Revision**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var myvar = 0
    func count() -> Int {
        return myvar
    }
    func incrementCount() {
        myvar += 1
    }
}
...
let vc = MyViewController()
Interval(1) {
    print(vc.count())
    vc.incrementCount()
}
```

**Suggested Reading**

[Pure Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)

[Swift style guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide)